# Is it possible to get a camera that has nearly the exact same camera quality (software and hardware) as a specific phone?

Tags: software, smartphone, used-equipment, kodak, low-budget

Recently I've been meaning to get a camera that looks, feels, and takes pictures nearly identical to the Apple iPhone 8+.

I mainly try to take sunset and sunrise photos, but I also take some general photos of scenery and scenes involving persons.

I currently use a Kodak EasyShare Z730 as it was the cheapest camera I could find at my local thrift store.

I have a budget of around $80, but would like the camera to be under $50. I also don't necessarily care about the hardware (to a certain extent), as I understand that a lot of camera improvement in smartphones nowadays is through software. I would finally like the camera to be digital, as I am not capable enough (at this point) to handle film.

(I'm okay with having to buy it from eBay or any other reseller marketplace)

I'm quite sorry if this type of question is not allowed, I just couldn't find an answer anywhere else.

Thanks,

-[K] IMSOASIAN

Comment: 1. What kind of characteristics of photos from iPhone you want to reproduce? 2. For this price tag better stay with the phone. 3. Questions about equipment recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @RomeoNinov 1.) The depth and stability of the photo, and the ability to zoom in without losing image quality 2.) Ah, well that sucks. I wonder if the PinePhone could replicate this? 3.) Ah sorry, I knew I was doing something wrong here.

Comment: What is your objective in replicating the phone performance?  You have the phone, so it seems you should be trying to improve something.  The phone has the advantage that (most people) always have it with them.  Zoom in without losing quality is wrong.  It just reflects the fact that you are not looking at the photos in enough detail to see the loss.  For quite a while the resolution of cameras was stuck at 14-20 MP, but my whole laptop screen is only 2MP, so if I look at a zoomed photo on my laptop I will not notice the loss if the zoom is not too great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cameras do very little inboard processing. What happens in an iPhone (or any smartphone for that matter) is typically done in "post-production" on a computer when taking photos with a dedicated camera. And while this  processing in the smartphone looks good on a smartphone screen, if you look close it is often a fairly dirty job, so I wouldn't want my camera to take pictures identical to those of an iPhone.

If you want a camera that does the same as a smartphone, it will require a powerful processor, a high-capacity battery, and cost the same as a smartphone.

Then, what you can get for what price is highly country-dependent. Around me for €50 I can get a top-of-the-line bridge camera from 2014. But the camera market in your country may be different (entry level compact cameras are in the €100-150 range when purchased new).

Comment: Could you give an example of one of the "top-of-the-line bridge" cameras from "2014"?

Comment: That one is gone (Sony bridge IIRC). Looking at a Coolpix P500 from 2011 for €50 (likely requires a new battery)...

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into buying it or a similar camera